# UItableview is moving up and down rather than scrolling inside

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with about 15 cells and `setScrollEnabled:YES`. The problem I am facing is this:

When I scroll, the entire table view moves. I.e.: If I scroll up, the table view moves up and covers the  top bar.

What I'd like to do is to **scroll within** the inside of `UITableView` so it doesn't move, only the cells/cell content within it move up/down (possibly even the use of a vertical indicator as well?).

I can't find anything on SO or a Google Search.

What I'm currently using is as follows:

```
#define NUMBER_ROWS 15

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if ([self.rearTableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [self.rearTableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];

    }
    if (IS_WIDESCREEN) {
        [self.rearTableView setScrollEnabled:YES];
        [self.rearTableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    }
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return NUMBER_ROWS;
}

- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 50;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        MenuCell *cell = (MenuCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        if (nil == cell)
        {
            cell = [[MenuCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        }
        [cell.textLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [cell.textLabel setHighlightedTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
        [cell.selectedBackgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor menuSelected]];

        if (indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"      Films";
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_film.png"];
            cell.imageView.highlightedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_film_active.png"];
            [cell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor menuGray]];
            [cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor menuParent]];
            //[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
            [[cell textLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:18]];

        }
        ....
}
```

Images of the issue:

UITableView moving down
[image: UITableView moving down]

UITableView moving up and covering the top bar
[image: UITableView moving up and covering the top bar]

Thanks

Comment: do you have UIScrollView inside your view controller?

Comment: @Ammar I haven't ever used UIScrollView, can you possible explain in an answer how I can go about it from scratch?

Comment: What I mean, you may have scroll in your view controller that effects scrolling inside the table view

Comment: Sounds like that's the issue but unsure how I can go about fixing it :/

Comment: can you add code from your viewDidLoad method?

Comment: looks normal, what about your storyboard? check if it is embed in scroll view in storyboard.

Comment: Sure thing. Will check now, 2 mins. Prefer moving to chat or continue on here? Thanks again @Ammar

Comment: prefer go to chat but you don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Ah, true - damn! Ok so in my nib I have attributes on the right for table view and scroll view. Scroll indicators: "Shows Horizontal indicators", Scrolling: "scrolling enabled".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65248/discussion-between-ammar-and-tfk300).